# How can I show minutes in frontend in tailwind datepicker in such way, than the user can see not all minutes only every 15 minutes?

Tags: datepicker, laravel-8, tailwind-css, laravel-blade

I have one problem with tailwind in my project. I have verion 1.1.0 of tailwind-datepicker, laravel 8.
Actually I see all minutes in frontend in my calendar. I have to configure datepicker with 15 minutes: 0-15-30-45.
Can somebody help me with tailwind? I have checked js-file and blade-file. I don't have idea, where I can find the place for configuration.
I can post the link to the documentation of this datepicker:
https://flowbite.com/docs/plugins/datepicker/

in the blade-file, where the new date will be created, it is the input for the start time:

```
 <x-input type="time" class="ml-2 w-2/5" x-mask="99:99" placeholder="HH:MM" name="starttime" id="starttime" required min="08:00" max="22:00"/>
```

Comment: Which datepicker? Also, Tailwind is a CSS framework; why would it have any affect on what is likely a JS datepicker? You'll need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73530247/edit), including adding more details about this datepicker, and some code; we won't be able to help much (or at all) unless you provide these details.

Comment: Is it a option to use a dropdown with just this 4 entries? (HTML `<select>` element)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with select, thank your for your answer.

```
                     <x-select name="start" id="start">
                            <?php for($i=8; $i<23; $i++)
                                {
                                ?> <option> <?php echo $i?> </option>
                                <?php }?>
                            </x-select>
                            <x-select>
                                <option>15</option>
                                <option>30</option>
                                <option>45</option>
                            </x-select>
```